# How do I find my Node/Express, Backbone, Postgres app's performance issues?

Tags: node.js, performance, postgresql, azure, backbone.js

**UPDATE:** I no longer believe the database to be my issue. I'm also seeing many second load times for static assets in this app.

I have an app running as an Azure Cloud Service. It's a Node app running Express framework for the backend and Backbone on the front-end. I have an Ubuntu virtual machine (also on Azure) running Postgres for the database.

At certain times of day, any view that requires a DB query (which is most of them) is really slow to load. Here's an example to illustrate. We have a paged view that performs a fairly complex query with a few joins and limits to 30 results. When I first loaded this view just before 8am, pages were loading in about 200ms. Now, pages are generally taking between 5 and 20 seconds to load.

Given the performance issue seems to only happen when a query is performed, I'm relatively sure this has something to do with my database, but I'm not sure where to start. Is it my VM? Is it the database design? Would running something like [pgBouncer](http://www.guguncube.com/1692/pgbouncer-installation-and-configuration-in-ubuntu) on the server fix the problem?

I've tried `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query mentioned in my example. The result was that the query should take 75ms which doesn't reflect the real-world performance I'm seeing in the app. I even created a few new indexes to try to make the joins run a little smoother, but made no difference at all best I could tell. Here's the output of the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Limit  (cost=128.40..154.59 rows=30 width=191) (actual time=73.254..73.375 rows=30 loops=1)
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=128.40..634.73 rows=580 width=191) (actual time=73.238..73.287 rows=30 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=128.40..627.48 rows=580 width=191) (actual time=21.556..67.711 rows=580 loops=1)
              ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=128.12..277.33 rows=580 width=187) (actual time=21.530..49.437 rows=580 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (sites.id = siteinfo.siteid)
                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=127.85..215.80 rows=616 width=114) (actual time=21.507..38.946 rows=616 loops=1)
                          Merge Cond: (sites.id = userssites.siteid)
                          ->  Index Scan using sites_pkey on sites  (cost=0.28..54.34 rows=616 width=82) (actual time=0.010..1.125 rows=616 loops=1)
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=127.57..152.29 rows=611 width=69) (actual time=21.485..31.958 rows=611 loops=1)
                                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=127.57..144.65 rows=611 width=61) (actual time=21.480..30.198 rows=611 loops=1)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=127.57..130.72 rows=1259 width=61) (actual time=21.465..23.196 rows=1259 loops=1)
                                            Sort Key: userssites.siteid
                                            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 226kB
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=20.84..62.75 rows=1259 width=61) (actual time=1.461..6.713 rows=1259 loops=1)
                                                  Hash Cond: (userssites.userid = users.id)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on userssites  (cost=0.00..24.59 rows=1259 width=41) (actual time=0.008..1.771 rows=1259 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=14.82..14.82 rows=482 width=28) (actual time=1.439..1.439 rows=482 loops=1)
                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 30kB
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..14.82 rows=482 width=28) (actual time=0.008..0.713 rows=482 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using siteinfo_pkey on siteinfo  (cost=0.28..52.73 rows=580 width=110) (actual time=0.011..4.958 rows=580 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((street1 IS NOT NULL) OR (street2 IS NOT NULL) OR (zip IS NOT NULL) OR (city IS NOT NULL) OR (state IS NOT NULL) OR (country IS NOT NULL))
              ->  Index Scan using agsfiles_pkey on agsfiles  (cost=0.28..0.59 rows=1 width=78) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=580)
                    Index Cond: (id = sites.agsfileid)
Total runtime: 73.594 ms
```

Curiously, my staging instance (which utilizes a distinct database with the same design running on the same database server as the production instance) seems to perform fine with queries coming back in 150-250ms at the same time production queries are taking 2.5 seconds.

How do I proceed from here to start finding and fixing this issue?

Comment: The usual culprits are strong locks being taken (`log_lock_waits` on newer Pg versions, check `pg_locks`) and excessive concurrent workers (check `pg_stat_activity`).

Comment: Thanks, @CraigRinger. I have run a couple of queries that I believe expose what you're talking about here, but I'm not sure quite what I'm looking at. Would I see tons of results if these were the problems? Running `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`, I get 8 results and `SELECT * FROM pg_locks pl LEFT JOIN pg_stat_activity psa ON pl.pid = psa.pid;` has 9.